# Prove that a Jordan measurable set of measure 0 is Riemann integrable

Tags: measure-theory, riemann-integration

My problem is: I have a set $A$ which is Jordan measurable, and I have a function  $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. I need to prove that if the measure of A is $0$, then $f$ is Riemann integrable and furthermore $\int_{A}f(x)dx = 0$.
 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is Jordan measureable it is bounded. The Riemann integral over $A$ is defined as $\displaystyle \int_Q f \chi_A$ where $Q$ is a rectangle containing $A$.

(1) Prove first that the integral of $f\chi_A$ over $Q$ actually exists by showing that  the integrand is continuous except on a set of measure $0$.

(2) Take any partition $P$ of $Q$. Every subrectangle $R$ of $P$ has nonzero content and cannot be contained in $A$. Thus, $R$ always contains a point where $f(x)\chi_A(x) = 0$ and

$$\inf_{x \in R} f(x)\chi_A(x) \leqslant 0 \leqslant \sup_{x \in R} f(x)\chi_A(x), $$

This implies that lower and upper Darboux sums satisfy $L(P, f\chi_A) \leqslant 0 \leqslant U(P,f \chi_A )$.  From here you should be able to prove that the integral (which falls between lower and upper sums) is $0$.

Comment: By $\chi_A$ you denoted the Jordan measure of $A$, right? I am asking you because I usually denote it by $\lambda_A $

Comment: @RaducuMihai: No -- that is not correct.  This is the indicator function: $\chi_A(x) = 1$ if $x \in A$ and $\chi_A(x) = 0$ if $x \notin A$.  We are dealing with Riemann integration.  In $\mathbb{R}^n$ Riemann integrals are defined first over rectangles where the notion of partitions into subrectangles makes sense. For arbitrary sets the integral is defined as I stated above.

Comment: Also I want to help you but I'm hesitant to take this further.  Questions without personal input tend to be closed and ultimately deleted.